# Cubic integer overflow

Tags: c

The following simple calculation causes an integer overflow:

```
void main(void) {
    int n = 1291;
    long cube = n*n*n;
    printf("Cube: %ld, n: %d", cube, n);
}
```

Output:

```
Cube: -2143282125, n: 1291
```

My thinking was that since the result of `n*n*n` is assigned to a `long`, the result should evaluate to 2151685171.  However, it appears that the result is calculated *first* into an `int`; because if `int n = 1291` is changed to `long n = 1291`, it works as expected.

---

**Question:**

Is the 'intermediary' result of `n*n*n` stored to `int` (the declared type) before being assigned to the `long` declaration? Or, more simply: **Why does `n*n*n` cause an integer overflow when being assigned to a `long` type?**

I have researched to find the answer first, unfortunately must be searching incorrectly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ladislus: "`long` is signed with 32 bits" -- Even on platforms where that were true, the *assumption* that `long` is of a specific width is an error.

Comment: `n * n * n` is an operation of only `int` types, so it is evaluated in `int`. The assignment to `long` happens only later.

Comment: @Ladislus - `long` is not the issue, nor the question; `long` works.  The question is why does `n*n*n` cause an integer overflow when being assigned to a `long` type.

Comment: Note that on some platforms (e.g. Microsoft Windows), `int` and `long` both have the same width. On such platforms, the issue mentioned in the question does not exist. A `long` is not necessarily larger than an `int`, although it is on some platforms, such as 64-bit Linux.

Comment: The `n*n*n` operation has no idea that you intend to assign the result to `long` or that it can overflow the `int n` type. Assuming you have chosen a type that is large enough to hold the cube value, you need to cast one of the operands: `(long)n*n*n`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @WeatherVane: you are perfectly right, but I would first write your solution as `((long) n) * n * n`, and only later as `(long)n*n*n`. If I see `(long)n*n*n`, it makes me think of `(long)(n*n*n)`, which is obviously wrong. :-)

Comment: @Dominique there is no need to parenthesise that. IMO it's clutter, not clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question resembles a lot to the typical division question:

```
int a = 7;
double b = a / 2;
=> b seems to be equal to 3 instead of 3.5, and in order to avoid this, you need to do:

double b = ((double)a) / 2; // or:
double b = a / 2.0; // which is the same as (double)2
```

So, I believe that you might benefit from the same reasoning, doing something like this:

```
int n = 1291;
long cube = ((long)n) * n * n;
```

Comment: While this answer shows code that might work, it does not explain the relevant rules for evaluating expressions in C.

Comment: As I understand the type promotion logic (implied by the answer), I've accepted and upvoted the answer, thank you.  However, I am in agreement with @EricPostpischil, in that the answer can be improved for more novice readers by including (or linking) detail as to *why* `n` should be cast as long during the calculation, to enforce promotion. Thanks again.